# SP implementation using Spring SAML extension with Google App Engine in Java

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I try to make a SP hosted on Google app engine, with a third party IdP, and I'm facing multiple problems.

I'm using Spring SAML extension for java. I was able to run the stand alone (not in GAE) demo app, from the official guide http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html using as IdP idp.ssocircle.com.

Now my problem comes whey I tried to integrate this code in my GAE project. When running with GAE I can get to the phase where I'm redirected to do the login on ssocircle.com and from there when I should be redirected back to my page I'm getting this error: "Error 401 Authentication Failed: Error decoding incoming SAML message", and on local GAE server logs I can see this message

"[INFO] Dec 17, 2014 5:21:23 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry [INFO] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Permission denied: Not allowed to issue a socket bind: permission denied."

I was wondering if this is a limitation from GAE regarding sockets: 1) Sockets are available only for paid apps (I don't have a paid app, but could consider this options) 2) You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets. 3) You cannot bind to specific IP addresses or ports. (for me this one sounds like it is my problem).

And whey I tried to deploy on GAE, the app remained in a start-up loop because of other errors regarding "nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")", that sounds like another GAE limitation to me.

At some point I was ready to gave up, because I was thinking that SAML Spring extension can't work with GAE, because of limitations present on GAE. But I see you have the same project running as a demo on GAE (or at least I think it is running on GAE because of the appspot part in domain name). https://saml-federation.appspot.com/saml/discovery?returnIDParam=idp&entityID=saml-federation.appspot.com

I would appreciate if you can give me some hints regarding my problems, and best would be if you could help me with the source code of this demo project (could not find it anywhere), and all configuration that is needed for GAE.

Comment: A similar problem is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262978/sso-implementation-using-shibboleth-with-google-app-engine-java

Comment: the demo might be on a hosted vm I guess, not sure about the domain names for that.

Comment: The demo is using a customized MetadataProvider which uses GAE APIs to make the Artifact resolution calls (your SocketException) and which doesn't attempt to start threads (modifyThreadGroup exception). I'll send you the code later.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a new repository https://github.com/vschafer/spring-security-saml-gae which includes instructions for deployment of Spring SAML applications on Google Application Engine. It also includes classes helping to avoid issues you're facing (sockets and threads).

In order to use it:

- include the jar created from the repo in your project
- use the provided `org.springframework...StaticFilesystemMetadataProvider` for loading of your metadata
- in case you are using HTTP-Artifact binding replace bean `org.springframework...ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl` with `org.springframework...google.ArtifactResolutionProfileGAE`

Please comment if you spot some mistakes in the documentation or code.